# How to ease left of body?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I'm trying to do a pop-out menu, and I have a bit of an issue.

I've applied:

```
.menu-side, .menu {
    -webkit-transition: left 0.2s ease;
    -moz-transition: left 0.2s ease;
    transition: left 0.2s ease;
}
```

`.menu` is set to the body, and `menu-side` to the pop-out menu. The left of both the menu and body is changed when the pop-out menu is loaded. But for some reason it isn't easing correctly?

Comment: Please show us the HTML, more of the CSS, and any Javascript/jQuery you are using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the initial value of [`left`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/left) property is `auto`.

Therefore, the browser doesn't know how to do the transition from `auto` to `180px`.

To fix it, you must set it to `0` initially:

```css
.menu {
    left: 0px;
    transition: left 0.2s ease;
}
.menu-open {
    left: 180px;
}
```

```css
.menu {
  left: 0px;
  transition: left 0.2s ease;
  background: red;
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
}
:checked ~ .menu { /* .menu-open */
  left: 180px;
}
```

```html
<input id="toggler" type="checkbox" />
<label for="toggler">Toggle</label>
<div class="menu"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would never animate the `body` element itself. You should always use a wrapper, the `body` has some special properties and doesn't always act you would expect a `div` to act. However, If you manually set `left: 0` on the `body` the transition will work.

```
body {
    left: 0;
}
```